# Architecture: managing pool of api keys

Tags: architecture, api-key, rate-limiting, google-search-api

**Background:**

- I am working on enabling google search on our platform using google's own [custom search JSON API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview).
- The platform is a `multi-tenant` architecture where each tenant can have multiple users.
- There is a daily upper limit of `10K` calls on each `API` key, so we plan to have to pool to cover the needs of our clients.
- This `API` will be directly called by the frontend code(UI).

**Looking for possible solutions on how to:**

1. provide a valid key from the pool to the frontend logic when a user logs in to the platform website (note that the user may or may not use embedded google search, but the frontend should always have a valid key with them in case the user performs an embedded google search).
2. track the number of times an `API` key has been used in order to know when a key has exhausted its quota.
3. what kind of store to use for storing these keys?
4. enable `rate-limiting on tenants or users so that everyone gets a fair share of total calls available.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this idea of UI calling directly an external API by having access to the API key doesn't sound good to me from a security perspective. I would still consider using a thin backend layer to validate the request before calling the external API.

Now to your question, Google APIs already have ways to [monitor API usage](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/monitoring), which is something I would consider in the first place, because depending on the scale of your application, keeping track of API usage might be problematic to manage.

You can also cap the [API usage per user](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/7035610) to make sure you don't reach that 10K limit, which is essentially what you're looking for - rate-limiting users if they reached their assigned quota. This works for some Google APIs as far as I see, needs some checking to see if it works for the search API as well.

Now if you have strong reasons to do it yourself, you can store the keys in a fast No-SQL cache, like [Redis](https://redis.io/). It may need some custom logic to always give you the API key which has the smallest number of invocations, but that can be figured out for sure.

Rate-limiting can be done using [Bucket4J](https://github.com/vladimir-bukhtoyarov/bucket4j) or a similar library.

Comment: if I introduce a backend layer, it will introduce network delays and we are habitual to instant google search results. This will affect the UX.

Comment: Absolutely, but the risk is to have an attacker consuming the entire quota of all keys, which will cause all the users to be rate-limited.